# Divisibility of combinatorial number with Lucas' Theorem

Tags: combinatorics

For how many non-negative integers n from 0 to 300 (inclusive), the combinatorial number ${300\choose n}$ is not divisible by 5?

I know how to use Lucas' Theorem to solve easy questions like finding remainder of ${100\choose 18}$ divided by 13, but can't figure out this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Lucas's theorem, if we write $n=125n_3+25n_2+5n_1+n_0$, then $\binom{300}n$ is divisible by $5$ if and only if $\binom{2}{n_3}\cdot\binom{2}{n_2}\cdot\binom0{n_1}\cdot\binom0{n_0}$ is. Note that this can only be divisible by $5$ if the product is actually $0$.

In other words, $\binom{300}n$ is *not* divisible by $5$ exactly when $n_2,n_3\le2$ and $n_1=n_0=0$. This gives us $3\cdot3\cdot1\cdot1=9$ options.

In particular, we have the following list of $n$ for which $\binom{300}n$ isn't divisible by $5$:
$$0,25,50,125,150,175,250,275,~\textrm{and}~300.$$

In general, if we replace $300$ with $m$ and $5$ with $p$, then the answer is exactly $\prod(m_i+1)$, where $m_i$ are the unique nonnegative integers with $m=\sum m_ip^i$.